# January 1,1900 birthday for Google Contacts

Tags: google-contacts

Google Contacts sets DOB (date of birth) to 1st Jan 1900 for my contacts by default. How can I remove this from multiple contacts at a time, or even all at once?

I have found a similar question on [this Google group link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/ruWQlV72juU) which is left un-answered.

Comment: I don't see that Google sets a default birthdate at all. I've added contacts directly and via import many times and have never gotten a default DOB. If I don't provide one it stays blank. How are you adding these contacts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Export your contacts

1. Log into https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?pli=1#contacts
2. Click on *More -> Export*
3. Select the group `My Contacts`
4. Select vCard export format.
5. Click on Export and save the file.
6. Open `contacts.vcf` in a text editor. Ideally [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or Notepad. Not Word as it'll probably make unwanted changes to the file.
7. Do a search and replace. Search for `BDAY:1900-01-01` and replace with `BDAY:`
8. Save the file with a different name (the original will be your backup).

## Delete your existing contacts

1. Go back to Google Contacts
2. Select all contacts within `My contacts`
3. Select *More -> Delete contacts*
4. Repeat until `My Contacts` is empty.

## Import your updated contacts

1. Click on *More -> Import*
2. Click on `Browse` and select your modified vcf file
3. Click on `Import` to import the modified contacts into Google.

Bear in mind that you will lose all contact pictures. I personally use [Sync.ME](http://www.sync.me/) (available for Android and iOS) after the last desktop application I had that did this stopped working.

Comment: Can you also help me with how to avoid adding a contact with default date in future, is there a setting. Or do I have to delete the default  DOB manually.

Comment: How are you adding/editing contacts? I use either the desktop site, an iPad or my Android phone and none of these set a default birthday date. Do you use an external program to sync contacts with something like Facebook and is it attempting to set the birthday incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

1. Export your Gmail Contacts as a CSV file.
2. Load the CSV into a spreadsheet application (Excel), or a text
   editor.
3. Modify the column ("O"=Birthday) which contains the Date of Birth information by using
   a Find/Replace All or just clear the data inside those cells manually.
4. Save the modified CSV and import it back into Gmail.

#### Reference:

- [Export Gmail Contacts](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/24911)
- [Import Contacts Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14024)